# ¿Cómo se puede traducir "hold his own" al español?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

Según google.com, "hold his own" significa:

> Mantener una posición de fuerza en una situación desafiante.

¿Existe alguna palabra que exprese justamente esto en español? ¿O solo palabras parecidas?

Comment: Si imagino una situación donde me gustaría expresar esta idea, creo que diría, *Pero Fulanito no se deja vencer tan fácilmente.* // Consulté Linguée, inglés -> francés, y encontré *se débrouiller*, que sí expresa bien la idea.  De ahí llegué a *Fulanito puede arreglarse las cosas [por su cuenta] [bastante bien]*.

Comment: En España diríamos "Fulanito puede arreglárselas [solo] [por sí mismo]", o simplemente "Fulanito puede arreglárselas".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En lenguaje coloquial urbano (en Argentina) se diría preferentemente "hacer el aguante",en lenguaje formal, creo que la mejor opción es "resistir". Pero en un lenguaje mas metafórico uno podría decir "poner el pecho".

Answer (score 4):

Podría depender del contexto, pero algunas con el mismo significado serían:

- Defenderse
- Saber defenderse
- Resistir
- Aguantar
- Apechugar

Comment: En algunos paises, se usa la frase "se defiende" con referencia a alguien que habla un idioma con fluidez, pero no como lengua madre.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la expresión más parecido en español sería "mantener el tipo", aunque depende de que se considere como mantener una posición de fuerza.

Un ejemplo de uso sería por ejemplo si se quiere expresar que un deportista que teoricamente habría de haber perdido con mucha diferencia contra otro en verdad, lo ha hecho por una diferencia bastante menor a la esperada inicalmente.

Con ello podría hacerse una frase como:

> El jugador mantuvo el tipo contra su contrincante

Answer (score 2):

En la línea de [lo indicado por muik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21251/1674) de *mantener el tipo*, yo me decantaría por algo así como

**mantenerse firme**

Que creo que encaja bien al conectar la idea de fuerza de la definición (recordemos, *Mantener una posición de **fuerza** en una situación desafiante*). Esta es una forma de decir que últimamente leo con frecuencia en medios de comunicación ([*El colectivo Baldomero Lozano pide al PSOE mantenerse firme en el no*](http://www.diariodeleon.es/noticias/leon/colectivo-baldomero-lozano-pide-psoe-mantenerse-firme-no_1093715.html), por ejemplo) y que cristaliza la idea de que uno queda fijo en una idea pese a las fuerzas que quieren *moverlo* hacia otras.